# How to join two tables with nested field?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
id | ciaps
 1 | a|b|c
```

An have a second table like:

```
cod | desc
  a | item a
  b | item b
  c | item c
```

I need a code to join this tables like:

```
id | ciaps
 1 | item a|item b|item c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_agg for concatenating string separated by '|' and convert it array_to_string to get the value expected format.

```
-- PostgreSQL (v11)
SELECT t1.id, t2.descr ciaps
FROM test1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(cod), '|') cod
                 , array_to_string(array_agg(descr), '|') descr
            FROM test2) t2
        ON t1.ciaps = t2.cod;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6fffc7f1da6a02a48018b3691c99ad17